# LifeCycle android app

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

Вроде есть два приложения с похожей архитектурой. В одном после того, как развернул приложение, появляется в логе onRestart(); onResume(); в другом нет.. свернул приложение, последнее что вижу в логе onStope();  а когда снова разворачиваю - черный экран... и снова сворачиваю - лог не меняется. Почему может такое происходить? в каких случаях не вызываются методы onRestart(); onResume()?

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    while(running){
        canvas  = null;
        try{
            canvas= this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
              if (canvas == null)
                continue;
            synchronized(surfaceHolder){
                this.gamePanel.update();     
                this.gamePanel.onDraw(canvas);
            }
        } finally{
                  if(canvas!=null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged");
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated");
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG,"surfaceDestroyed");
    //посылаем потоку команду на закрытие и дожидаемся,
    //пока поток не будет закрыт.
   boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false); // ну жна ли эта строка. без нее после сворачивания игры черный экран.
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // пытаемся снова остановить поток thread
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил , не помню что конкретно послужило решением, но вот основные: переменная которая запускает игровой цикл while (running) передается сразу же из метода onPause, чтобы скорее прекратить вычисления в потоке. Если поток не занят вычислениями он быстрее остановится. Основная проблема заключалась в том, что игровой цикл запускался сразу же после OnResume. После того как сделал запуск игрового цикла нажатием на кнопку Продолжить, проблема белого экрана исчезла.

Answer (score 0):

Вот несколько выдержек из одной умной книжки. может помочь:

> The onResume function is executed after the OnStart event or after the
>   current  activity is switched to the background. When the user views
>   this activity again, if it has not been destroyed, and if onStop
>   events have not been performed (activities continue to exist in the
>   task)...
>
> After the onStop event is executed, if the activity and the process it
>   resides in have not been systematically destroyed, or if the user
>   views the activity again, the onRestart event(s) of the activity are
>   executed. The  onRestart event skips the onCreate event activities and
>   directly executes the onStart events.

[image: Жизненный цикл активити]:

Comment: ни чем не помогло. я видел это уже не раз. после onStop() у меня ничего не происходит ни onRestart() ни onCreate() . А в другом точно таком же приложении все работает. я даже отличие в коде не могу  найти и понять почему в одном проекте все запускается, а в другом нет.

Comment: ни у одного меня проблемы с черным экраном , когда использую расширяет SurfaceView реализует SurfaceHolder.Callback.

Comment: поставил логи в переопределяемые методы SurfaceHolder.Callback.  а именно  в surfaceChanged, surfaceCreated, surfaceDestroyed.  и вот результат. если нажать на блокировку экрана вызывается  onPause
 onSaveInstanceState
 Stopping...  но игра продолжает идти, слышны звуки.. (почему?вроде же стоп? ) после всё восстанавливается onRestart,onStart, onResume .  а вот если не блокировать экран, а нажать назад или свернуть приложение то onPause и surfaceDestroyed.. почему surfaceDestroyed вызывается ? и как это исправить.

Comment: @Turalllb покажите код?

Comment: @Turalllb onStop вообще выполняется? что показывают логи? в обоих приложениях.  насколько понимаю, андройд не гарантирует время вызова onStop. попробуйте поставить логи (разные) на onFreeze, onPause и onStop, понажимать кнопки и посмотреть в какой момент какое событие происходит.

Comment: Завтра буду дома и сделаю. Он стоп не выполняется это точно.  Ставится пауза,  а потом дестрой метод из Callback, это не дестрой из нативных методов. Чтобы понятней было я покажу весь код завтра как буду дома. У меня подозрения на код написанный в доп. потоке,  потому что сама архитектура работает как надо в другом приложении, в логах все вызовы последовательно.

Comment: В общем ситуация такая. Запускаю на эмуляторе и вот логи :onPause, onSaveInstanceState, Stop, Thread: surfaceDestroyed (это приложение свернуто) разворачиваю и вот логи onRestart, onStart, onResume, Thread: surfaceCreated, Thread: surfaceChanged. И даже игровая ситуация не меняется, т.е. переменные все сохраняются...А теперь когда подключаю телефон Xaiomi redmi note 3 pro : во первых игра началась , а экран белый и в логе Connected to process 7436 on device xiaomi-redmi_note после появления в логе Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@67586d7 time:69600607  на экране появляетсявсё

Comment: Если экран потушить кнопкой блокировки игрова работает с выключенным экраном а в логе такое : onPause onSaveInstanceState Stop а после включения экрана onRestart onStart onResume ( т.е. методы SurfaceHolder.Callback не срабатывают)  Если нажать на кнопку домой логи такие onPause  потом  Thread: surfaceDestroyed и потом только onSaveInstanceState   Stop . И когда пробую развернуть :onRestart, onStart, onResume  , surfaceCreated и потом ошибка , что поток уже запущен java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started

Comment: ну вот код где возможно, есть ошибки я приложил. И в интернете нашел немного инфы о том, что метод которым я останавливаю поток устаревший и не безопасный, поэтому возможно на моем новом телефоне не работает, а на эмуляторах всё норм.. вот например похожая тема http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148186/thread-already-started-when-resuming-the-activity     пока пытаюсь вникнуть